# How can I rate the accessibility of my ASP.NET MVC3 HTML5 web application?

Tags: css, html, accessibility, web-standards

Is there a formal standard I can use to to rate the accessibility, especially for visually impaired people, of my MVC3 web application? If there are various standards, as I suspect, which should I give preference to for a web application primarily targeted at people with no or minimal visual impairment, but strongly wanting to offer as much as possible to visually impaired people? This is a learning management application, so wide accessibility is important.

I am trying to stick to best practices in terms of HTML and CSS semantics and such like things, documented in the handful of books I have, and I am using HTML5 validation in Visual Studio for my Razor views. What other tools can I use, preferably on the development side, before I deploy and can use the various online validators? Are the any online rating tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Standard (and reference list)**

The W3C standard is **[WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag.php)**.
The WCAG 2.0 Recommendation tries to be technologically agnostic and to apply to all kinds of websites, even web apps but the consequence is that it's rather unspecific. HTML/CSS/Script Techniques (as well as the Failure ones and Flash/Pdf/Smil if you use them) and the Understanding part are good reads.

For daily auditing I prefer to use:

> [**AccessiWeb** 2.2 reference
>   list](http://www.accessiweb.org/index.php/accessiweb-22-english-version.html),
>   "*a methodology to verify conformance to WCAG 2.0*" that "*facilitates
>   (its) understanding and implementation*".

There are references to WCAG 2.0 Success Criteria and Techniques but alas no links. Hyperlinks exist on the french version but weren't added on the english one, alas (I'll try to fix it with them this month).

The script part, essential to webapps, is again partly unspecific but that's because it's hard to be so without having 10x as tests! There are thousands of things to do with JS when there are a hundred of HTML elements.

EDIT 2014: this checklist has been updated to new techniques in HTML5/ARIA (an awesome work imho) but only in french. [AccessWeb HTML5/ARIA (in french)](http://www.accessiweb.org/index.php/accessiweb-html5aria-liste-deployee.html) May be translated in english in 2014 or 2015 or try an online translation service ;) 70% of tests are common with AccessiWeb 2.2 and the new tests are up to date HTML5/ARIA techniques already working in modern websites with the browsers and screen readers quoted in Annexes.

[**ARIA**](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria), as in Accessible RIA, is another work from W3C-WAI:

> *(ARIA) especially helps with dynamic content and advanced user
>   interface controls developed with Ajax, HTML, JavaScript, and related
>   technologies.*

No doubt this is the future of accessible web apps but its support is a work in progress in browsers and assistive technologies. Also old screen readers'll never be compatible with ARIA and they're very slowly being replaced for newer versions because they cost A LOT (thousand(s) of USD/EUR for JAWS).
Thus webdevs must always create apps compatible with both old plain techniques (using tab key and space to access information and interact with it) and new ones (manipulating a tree with arrow keys, being informed of changes in a Live region while reading another part of the page).

- ARIA is complicated, needs time and experience, etc
- ARIA doesn't replace WCAG 2.0; huge improvements'll be seen with WCAG 2.0 only.
- not everything is as complicated as a tree implementation. Landmark roles are very easy to add in any website for example.

If you use jQuery UI, there exists an accessible version of popular modules/scripts: http://hanshillen.github.com/jqtest/
It isn't perfect yet but it's far better than the original. In my experience, you can't mix the legacy jQuery UI scripts and these ones (though I didn't try for too long, I could easily be wrong).

**Testing**

I wrote about [2 useful services, **Opquast** and **Tanaguru**, in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764570/command-line-software-for-testing-accessibility/8770455#8770455). The other answer from BrendanMcK related to automated tests is a must read.

- **WAVE** (fluffmyboner already wrote about it in the other answer) both exist as a toolbar and as a webservice. Main difference afaik: the WAVE toolbar'll analyze the DOM of your page while the webservice'll analyze the HTML+CSS sent but won't execute any JS
- **TAW** (select *inglès* than WCAG 2.0) is another service for analyzing a few criteria

Answer (score 1):

[Wave](http://wave.webaim.org/) is my go-to for accessibility validation, although I'm not too sure about what you can use to check pre-deployment.

Comment: Thanks. Wave looks useful, but I'm really looking for a standard first, and something for checking or validating second.